# Create a text based on survey inputs?

Tags: survey, qualtrics, surveymonkey, google-surveys

I am wondering if there is a platform whereby a person being asked a set of questions through a survey and then the survey creates a text based on his or her input.

Say for example

```
Q1) have you done fire test
Answer person 1) yes
Answer person 2) no

If yes
another follow up question on Q1) have you tried doing this ccc
Answer person 1) no
```

The other question is

```
Q2) Were you able to run 50 mile
Answer person 1) No
Answer person 2) yes
```

Based on these results, I want the survey to print automatically different response to each person

> For person 1: Although you have done the fire test you weren't able to
>   do the CCC. Furthermore, you weren't able to run the 50 mile. So you
>   are unsuccessful for this post. Good luck in trying again next month.

However, a different result would be printed for person 2

> For person 2: it is good that you were able to run the 50 miles but it
>   is sad that you haven't done the fire test and it entails like the
>   ccc. Therefore, you were close to being a successful candidate. Good
>   luck trying next time.

My question: is there a way to automatically do this, if so how? Do I need to code it? Which platform to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Qualtrics using display logic.

Comment: display logic only shows questions based on one answer result not many (conditionally and unconditionally). Could Qualtrics generate a text based on the result of all the inputs?

Comment: You can include multiple conditions from multiple questions or variables in display logic.  The text would be separate Descriptive Text questions with display logic. You can also pipe variables into the text, but you wouldn't need that in your example.